# Facebook Connect Server-Side GetLoginStatus using ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, facebook, authentication, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am currently using the Facebook Javascript SDK and the Facebook C# SDK (soley for retrieving user graph objects).

Everything so far is going great except for the following scenario:

- User logs into Facebook
- User opens a new browser window and visits my
  site

Using the Javascript SDK, I can use the FB.getLoginStatus method to determine if they are connected or not (which they are in this scenario as I have previously authorized my site/app for the facebook login).

However, I need to be able to detect upon the homepage of my site loading for the first time, ideally server-side, if we are in this 'connected' state, and if so, render some different content to screen (logged in vs not logged in).

I can't currently see a server-side method in the Facebook C# SDK that enables me to do the equivalent of FB.getLoginStatus (clientside).

I should point out that any subsequent changes to the users loginstatus is handled via subscribing to the auth.authResponseChange event and all is working fine there, but its the first time page load when the user first hits the site that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this on the server with any Facebook SDK. You must detect the user's status with the Facebook Javascript SDK. The reason for this is because this information is stored in cookies that are either only readable by facebook.com or that are on you domain, but were set by Facebook and should not be parsed by your app.

You can parse the cookies on your domain if you like, but it isn't recommended because Facebook considers those cookies to be an internal implementation detail and does not guarantee their contents. They could change at any time and break your app.

Comment: so what is the recommended solution? Without rewriting his app to be entirely js based, what do you do? call the JS lib, then on response refresh the page having made an ajax call serverside or something horribly laggy like that? meh...

Comment: i suppose you could set your own cookie on your domain indicating the status, but that seems hacky too...

Comment: Having the same issue Andrew. Trying to figure out how to "refresh" the page once I know the user has "connected" to the app but their user session expired.  I was thinking having a modal appear and say "hey we noticed you were here before, click okay to refresh the page" or something awful like that.